# can't see progress bar

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, android-dialog

I am using a custom Dialog class to display image, and for some reason, the progress bar that inside the layout is not visible until the image is fully loaded.
I am using glide and if I call  `fullImageProgreesBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
I can see the progress bar above the already loaded image.

I want to show the progress bar before the image is loaded.

**My Dialogs class:**

```
public class FullSizeImageDialog extends Dialog {
private ImageView imageView;
private ProgressBar fullImageProgreesBar;
private Context dialogContext;

public FullSizeImageDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_size_image_dialog);
    dialogContext = context;
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.full_size_image);
    fullImageProgreesBar = findViewById(R.id.fullImageProgreesBar);
}

public void setImageFullSize(Uri imageUri) {
    Glide.with(dialogContext).load(imageUri)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    fullImageProgreesBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(dialogContext, "No image available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    fullImageProgreesBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }
            }).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

**My layout file for the dialog:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/fullImageProgreesBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/full_size_image" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/full_size_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/new_question"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Things that did not solve this problem for me :

- Change the `ProgressBar` elevation value from the XML
- Change the `ProgressBar` size
- Change the order or the elements inside `ConstaintLayout` (The `ProgressBar` was both above and below the `ImageView` in the XML file and the editor)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your image is math_parent , the progresbar is behind

Comment: @Igmer Rodriguez any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If you add `android:visibility="invisible"` in `ImageView` in your XML is the `ProgressBar` visible?

Comment: @ElectroWeak, I can't see is with invisible inside ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to change the visibility of progress bar to visible when the image is loaded in `onResourceReady`. Change this

```
fullImageProgreesBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

to this

```
fullImageProgreesBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```